# Why does gcloud not see my managed notebook?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have a Vertex AI managed notebook in `europe-west1-d`. I try both (locally and in the notebook):

```
gcloud notebooks instances list --location=europe-west1-d
gcloud compute instances list --filter="my-notebook-name" --format "[box]"
```

and both return nothing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a Vertex AI managed notebook, it is expected that the instance won't appear on your project. By design, the notebook instance is created in a Google managed project and is not visible to the end user.

But if you want to see instance details of your managed notebooks, you can use the Notebooks API to send a request to [runtimes.list](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.runtimes/list). See example request:

```
project=your-project-here
location=us-central1 #adjust based on your location

curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
"https://notebooks.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${project}/locations/${location}/runtimes"
```

Response output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. OK I suppose that design sort of makes sense. On the other hand they cost  a lot of money so would be good to be able to see them easily.